# Adding smaller tables with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I came to a situation where I had to make a query where I select content from few tables, I had no problem with 3 tables, I got to generate something like shown bellow.

```
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+
| Access ID  |  Client  |  Seller  |  Manager  |  Function  |
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

- `Access ID` comes from table `BO`
- `Client` comes from table `BO`
- `Seller` comes from table `BO`
- `Manager` comes from table `BO2`
- `Function` comes from table `CM3`

My code for the `JOIN`'s is:

```
SELECT BO.accessid, BO.client, BO.seller_name, BO2.manager, CM3.func FROM BO
JOIN BO2 ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
JOIN CM3 ON CM3.seller_number = BO.seller_number
```

Now I want to add the table `u_numbers`, but when I add `JOIN u_numbers n ON n.bostamp = BO.bostamp`  the results of my query somehow lower from 49 to 26 rows.

Every other table has around 20 columns, but the `u_numbers` table only has 5, with a lot less rows, but even then I thought that when I added this table, the number of rows that the query returned would be the same as this one, but this table has 38 rows.

Table structure for `u_numbers`:

```
+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
| u_numbersstamp  |  bostamp  |  number  |  order  |  Portability  |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
```

My goal with this query would be to add a row on the query for every number where `order <> 1`, and for this I tried

```
CASE WHEN n.order <> 1 THEN n.number ELSE bo.accessid END
```

This code worked so I if I could get the query to show the full rows then I would get it correctly. I also had `(NOLOCK)` in every table and then I tried to remove it to see if it changed anything but it didn't.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` so you don't lose any rows.

Comment: It worked, I get 62 rows now. Thank you very much

Comment: For more information on join types have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)